# Strong shock at the start of a moving in first gear

Tags: manual-transmission, suzuki, vibration, alto

I have Suzuki alto 2016 with manual gearbox. (Small car with 1.0 liter engine with 3 cylinders)

Sometimes, not always when I start moving in first gear at the moment when the engine speed equals the wheels speed (the moment when I need to release the clutch) I feel and hear a very strong shock in the whole car.

The strange thing that months can pass and it may not occur again.
It mostly happens if I drive in a hilly area, but it doesn't end until I give the car a rest with a shutdown engine.

What do you think it could be?

I think if these were the motor mounts I would experience the problem regularly.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

Motor mounts are a possibility but I would expect the problem to show up at other times as well.  Basically anytime the engine is putting pressure on the mount and it's able to move.

Some other possibilities:

1. Broken gear in the transmission.
2. Bent or worn shift fork
3. Failing CV shaft joint
4. Broken suspension component
5. Worn or damaged clutch

Comment: I would double check the motor mounts - I once drove a Mazda Miata which would shake very hard when launching the car, but as long as the long as the launch was gentle, you would not notice.